# How many missions until D-Dog grows up?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

How many missions until dog grows up? I had to go back to extract but I have done missions 1-10 so far and still hasn't grown.

Answer (score 3):

After extracting D-Dog, you need to complete six more story missions (replays count) before he grows up. You must also have completed at least three of the missions between mission 7 though mission 10 (inclusive), which count toward the six missions you need. ([Source](http://www.gamesradar.com/how-to-get-d-dog-buddy-metal-gear-solid-5/))